# Сложности со свойством object-fit внутри flex

Tags: css, flexbox, адаптивность

Я хочу сделать первый раздел страницы, совпадающий по размеру с окном.
В нем присутствует шапка и блок с картинкой, которая, сохраняя пропорции, заполняет место, оставшееся от шапки. Я использую `flex` для растягивания контейнера с картинкой до нужного размера, но свойство `object-fit: cover` у картинки при этом не работает. Для примера, без флекса - всё ок. (если подвигаете ширинур вьюпорта - сразу видно)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: beige;
}

.first-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.first-show {
  background-color: #ccc;
  flex: auto;
}

.second-screen {
  height: 100vh;
}

.second-show {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-screen">
  <header>header
  </header>
  <div class="first-show">
    <img class="" src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Cool-High-Resolution-Wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="First slide">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="second-screen">
  <div class="second-show">
    <img class="" src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Cool-High-Resolution-Wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="First slide">
  </div>
</div>
```

Собственно вопросы: почему и как обойти?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока увидел один способ решения: обернуть картинку в блок с 
`position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;`
Это больше похоже на хак, поэтому надеюсь на альтернативные способы.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: beige;
}

.first-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.first-show {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ccc;
  flex: auto;
}

.img-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-screen">
  <header>header
  </header>
  <div class="first-show">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img class="" src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Cool-High-Resolution-Wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

img динамически не растягивается на высоту элемента. Решения: если блок состоит только из картинки, то обертка div не нужна, а если в блоке будет контент - лучше картинку задавать через background(опять же поддержка ie11). Ниже приведу пример с сохранением img.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: beige;
  flex:0 0 auto;
}

.first-screen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}

.first-show {
  background-color: #ccc;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.second-show {
  height: 100vh;
}
img {
  width:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-screen">
  <header>header
  </header>
    <img class="first-show" src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Cool-High-Resolution-Wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="second-screen">
    <img class="second-show" src="http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Cool-High-Resolution-Wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg" alt="First slide">
</div>
```

Comment: Не понял, в чём выгода. Перестал работать `object-position`.

Comment: 1) Меньше  кода. 2) object-position работает(проверял в Chrome и Firefox)

Comment: Но он же у вас не работает даже прямо здесь. и я в хроме проверяю.
Посмотрите, где начало картинки в первом блоке и во втором. Во втором она по центру по вертикали выставлена.

Comment: В первом блоке помимо картинки ещё и header высотой в 100px есть. Само собой видимая области картинки будет отличаться, т.к. работает object-fit:cover. В инспекторе кода посмотрите как отличается картинка с заданным object-position и без него.

Comment: C разными значениями object-position

Comment: И всё-таки не просто же так у меня картинка в отдельном блоке поселилась, относительно которого центровалась.
Цитирую свой вопрос:
"В нем присутствует шапка и блок с картинкой, которая, сохраняя пропорции, заполняет место, оставшееся от шапки."
Оставшееся место.